# Let arrow marker point in the direction of another marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a Google Maps application where a user can search for a location. This location must point into the direction of a predefined marker.

Given the following pieces of code:

The predefined marker:

```
      var station = new google.maps.LatLng(52.375401, 5.218824);

      var stationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:   station,
        map:        map,
        });
```

The marker that will be placed on the location that the user searched:

```
      var direction = new google.maps.LatLng(52.376423, 4.887234);

      var directionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:   direction,
        map:        map,
        draggable:  false,
        title:      "test"
        });

      directionMarker.setIcon(({
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 6
        }));
```

***How can I make sure that the direction marker (i.e the marker from the user search result) always points to the predefined marker?***

I'm making use of the Google Maps API v3.

I've created a jsFiddle, which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fgdan8wq/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @MrUpsidown, yes. I've just added the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgdan8wq/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here you go:

1. Use the `google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW` so that it points to the north.
2. Add the Geometry library to be able to compute a heading.
3. Use the rotation parameter on your direction icon.

Here is how to [compute the heading](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) from your direction marker to the station:

```
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(direction,station);
```

Then use it to rotate your icon accordingly:

```
directionMarker.setIcon({
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    scale: 6,
    rotation: heading
});
```

You also had one unnecessary pair of `()` in the above code which I have removed.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uepc2f8n/)</kbd>

Comment: @MrUpsideDown,

Thank you very much! This works! However, When I change the coordinates of station to 21.422492, 39.826196 and for direction I chose a place in the north-east, like China, Thailand or Russia, then the direction is not correct. It points too much to the left.
Do you know why?

see here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uepc2f8n/5/)

Comment: Yes, I know why. Because the earth is round! :-) http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uepc2f8n/6/

Comment: @Nazeem: when the arrow must not be clickable you may use a hidden polyline with a IconSequence instead, the marker will point into the desired direction then. http://jsfiddle.net/9f8dy5p4/

Comment: @Dr.Molle Interesting solution indeed! The polyline (geodesic mode off) will point right at the marker. Good catch!

Comment: Another approach(without a polyline) that calculates the heading based on the Point-coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/uepc2f8n/27/